# How to run a batch file of server(which runs forever) and get the control back to the java program without closing that batch

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a java program:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c callServer.bat");
int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
```

Which is calling the batch file "callServer.bat":

```
@echo on
cd bin
call shutdown 2011
call server.bat
```

This batch file is calling server.bat file which is a server batch file which should run forever during the program. I want to get the control back after starting server.bat to my java program which will do other stuff. Please help me as I have spent so much time on it and could not get any solution.

Comment: i believe this involves creating a new thread or process.  best i can do

Answer (score 4):

Could be as simple as running the process in a different thread. This will execute the process in a separate thread and allow your main thread to continue while the batch file runs:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c callServer.bat");
        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
    }
};

thread.start();
```

Comment: I got the answer ;;; I need to use "start" callServer.bat instead of "call" callServer.bat... Thanks all for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the batch file from a separate thread which can be a deamon thread so that it won't exit till all your other user threads have not finished.

hope you find this of any use

Comment: Yes Aman, I think I need to go this way.. well I will try it with thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Process.exitValue() function to get the exit value without waiting for the program to close, however that obviously won't work if the program is still running.

If you wanted too you could do something like:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c callServer.bat");
while(condition){
   try{
      exitVal = proc.exitValue();
      System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
   }
   catch(Exception e){/*do nothing*/}
   //other code goes here
}
```

Kind of ugly, but you could do that if you're not comfortable with threading.  But using a thread would be the correct way to do it.